# How to sort Object Array Collection by value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraycollection

So I have this result from database:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#538 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#536 (3) {
           ["col_header"]=>
           string(7) "other_1"
           ["col_order"]=>
           int(12)
           ["data"]=>
           string(13) "asdgasdgfasdg"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#545 (3) {
           ["col_header"]=>
           string(7) "other_2"
           ["col_order"]=>
           int(10)
           ["data"]=>
           string(10) "dfhgsdhgsd"
       }
       [2]=>
       object(stdClass)#533 (3) {
           ["col_header"]=>
           string(7) "other_3"
           ["col_order"]=>
           int(11)
           ["data"]=>
           string(1) "s"
       }
}
```

Now, how can I sort its result based on value of `col_order`?The result should be like:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#538 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#545 (3) {
           ["col_header"]=>
           string(7) "other_2"
           ["col_order"]=>
           int(10)
           ["data"]=>
           string(10) "dfhgsdhgsd"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#533 (3) {
           ["col_header"]=>
           string(7) "other_3"
           ["col_order"]=>
           int(11)
           ["data"]=>
           string(1) "s"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#536 (3) {
           ["col_header"]=>
           string(7) "other_1"
           ["col_order"]=>
           int(12)
           ["data"]=>
           string(13) "asdgasdgfasdg"
        }
}
```

I've tried using `asort()` here but it seems it only supports associative array. Is there any way I can sort this one out?

Comment: You want http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Why you are not using orderBy on your query? As I thought you were using laravel elquent so you can use orderBy(''col_order) on your query

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan Thanks for that one. I haven't thought of it! It solves my problem, will use the answers on my future scenario,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
$test = array(array("col_header" => "other_1",
                    "col_order" => 12,
                    "data" => "asdgasdgfasdg"),
              array("col_header" => "other_2",
                    "col_order" => 10,
                    "data" => "dfhgsdhgsd"),
              array("col_header" => "other_3",
                    "col_order" => 11,
                    "data" => "s"));

usort($test, function($a, $b)
             {
                 if ($a["col_order"] == $b["col_order"])
                     return (0);
                 return (($a["col_order"] < $b["col_order"]) ? -1 : 1);
             });

var_dump($test);
```

**Output :**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'col_header' => string 'other_2' (length=7)
      'col_order' => int 10
      'data' => string 'dfhgsdhgsd' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'col_header' => string 'other_3' (length=7)
      'col_order' => int 11
      'data' => string 's' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'col_header' => string 'other_1' (length=7)
      'col_order' => int 12
      'data' => string 'asdgasdgfasdg' (length=13)
```

But I suggest you to sort your results directly from the SQL query :

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
...
ORDER BY col_order ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php - it sorts by a user-defined comparison function. Replace `a` with `col_order` in the following snippet:

```
<?php

$class1 = new stdClass();
$class1->a = 1;
$class2 = new stdClass();
$class2->a = 2;
$class3 = new stdClass();
$class3->a = 3;

$input = [$class3,$class2,$class1];

var_dump($input);

usort($input, function($a, $b) {
      if ($a->a == $b->a) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->a < $b->a) ? -1 : 1;
});

var_dump($input);
```

https://3v4l.org/9ELKp

As you are using Illuminate you might instead want to look at https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderBy too and use that instead.

Edit from the comments: using PHP 7+ you can make use of the spaceship operator to simplify the comparison function:

```
usort($input, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->a <=> $b->a;
});
```

Comment: The body of the function could be a oneliner with spaceship operator in php7: `return $a->a <=> $b->a;`

Comment: @FilipHalaxa Thank you, I will add it as addition to my answer.